# Vacuum sealer exclusively for canning jars?

Tags: storage-method, canning, vacuum

I'm looking for a vacuum sealer just to vacuum seal canning jars.  Presently I use a traditional vacuum sealer for bags that has an accessory port.  It's bulky and because it's designed for bags as well requires you to press some latches to seal the vacuum chamber every time you seal a new jar.  It's cumbersome and inconvenient.

Ideally there would be a compact device designed just for creating a vacuum that I could use for the canning jars.  Ideally it would be something I could keep on the counter for quickly resealing a jar and flip a switch to power it on/off.

I've seen that you can use manual brake bleeder hand pump, but I'm looking for something electric as I open and vacuum seal mason jars daily, and from what I hear the manual pumping is a significant amount of labor.

If there isn't a dedicated device for this, I'm wondering if there is a product that at least doesn't require you to re-seal the vacuum chamber after vacuuming each jar.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it's any less bulky, but this one is dedicated to canning [Vacucanner](http://vacucanner.com/index.html). It does several cans at a time. Here's a [review](http://www.thesurvivalpodcast.com/review-of-the-vacucanner-dry-canning-system)

If you like DIY projects, you might be interested in this video. [DIY Vacuum Canner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cV4gIX3rWs)

Comment: Thanks very much for letting me know about this.  This won't meet my needs at all, but it does certainly answer the question as asked.  I was doubtful there was any product on the market dedicated to vacuum sealing cans, so it's great to learn that there is one.